# [iPhone]how to add transition animation or overlay view when screen is rotating

Tags: iphone, animation, rotation

My application has some screens support landscape mode which load some more data and have to  re-render GUI, and one of them will load another view in landscape mode. But its seem the screen would be rotated before re-rendered or load another view, it is not nice looking.

So it would be better if there is an animation or a view to be shown when rotating.

Does anyone know how to do this please help me! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either one (or both); display additional animations or display a different view while rotating. I'm assuming you're working with a UIViewController, check out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (specifically, 'Handling View Rotations').

Override both [willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a) and [didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation%3a) to add and then remove your placeholder view.

You will need to override [willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a) to perform any animations.